# Trying to use Tab to jump between JTextFields vertically (using Custom FocusTraversalPolicy)

Tags: java, swing, awt

This is my first database simulator GUI, I'm having a hard time navigating with TAB through the user input text fields. My desire is to navigate in this order: From name to 1st last name, to 2nd last name, to age, to phone number, to address and finally to e-mail. I honestly just copied the code for a custom Focus Traversal Policy and was hoping it would work but it isn't. I don't know if I should even call it on the Listener class or is this redundant?

Here's the code, I'm sorry it got so long =S (omitted libraries to comply w/post max length):

public class UserFormNew {

```
private JTextField idtf;
private JTextField nametf;
private JTextField ln1tf;
private JTextField ln2tf;
private JTextField agetf;
private JTextField pntf;
private JTextField addresstf;
private JTextField emtf;
private JTable t;
private DefaultTableModel dtm;
private JTableHeader header;
private int idCount = 0;
private int rowSelected;
private boolean ed = false;
private String[] selRowInfoGotten;
private List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>();
private JPanel dataIn;

public UserFormNew() {

    // Containers
    JFrame mainF = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainP = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 5));
    dataIn = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel table = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(20, 10));

    // Fonts
    Font plain = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    Font plaint = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
    Font bold12 = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12);

    // Data-In
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    Insets topLeftLabel = new Insets(20, 20, 2, 2);
    Insets midLeftLabel = new Insets(2, 20, 2, 2);
    Insets botLeftLabel = new Insets(2, 20, 20, 2);
    Insets topMidTF = new Insets(20, 2, 2, 20);
    Insets midMidTF = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 20);
    Insets botMidTF = new Insets(2, 2, 20, 20);
    Insets topMidLabel = new Insets(20, 30, 2, 2);
    Insets midMidLabel = new Insets(2, 30, 2, 2);
    Insets botMidLabel = new Insets(2, 30, 20, 2);
    Insets topRightInsets = new Insets(20, 2, 2, 20);
    Insets midRightInsets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 20);
    Insets botRightInsets = new Insets(2, 2, 10, 20);

    JLabel id = new JLabel("Id");
    id.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = topLeftLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(id, gbc);

    JLabel name = new JLabel("Name");
    name.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = midLeftLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(name, gbc);

    JLabel ln1 = new JLabel("1\u00B0 Lastname");
    ln1.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = midLeftLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(ln1, gbc);

    JLabel ln2 = new JLabel("2\u00B0 Lastname");
    ln2.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = botLeftLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(ln2, gbc);

    JLabel age = new JLabel("Age");
    age.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = topMidLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(age, gbc);

    JLabel pn = new JLabel("Phone Number");
    pn.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = midMidLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(pn, gbc);

    JLabel address = new JLabel("Address");
    address.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = midMidLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(address, gbc);

    JLabel em = new JLabel("E-Mail");
    em.setFont(bold12);
    gbc.insets = botMidLabel;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(em, gbc);

    JLabel emptyTop = new JLabel("         ");
    gbc.insets = topRightInsets;
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(emptyTop, gbc);

    JLabel emptyMid1 = new JLabel("         ");
    gbc.insets = midRightInsets;
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(emptyMid1, gbc);

    JLabel emptyMid2 = new JLabel("         ");
    gbc.insets = midRightInsets;
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(emptyMid2, gbc);

    JLabel emptyBot = new JLabel("         ");
    gbc.insets = botRightInsets;
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(emptyBot, gbc);

    idtf = new JTextField("");
    idtf.setFont(plain);
    idtf.setEditable(false);
    idtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    idtf.addKeyListener(new NumericList());
    gbc.insets = topMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.4;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(idtf, gbc);

    nametf = new JTextField("");
    nametf.setFont(plain);
    nametf.setEditable(true);
    nametf.addKeyListener(new AlphabeticList());
    gbc.insets = midMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.4;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(nametf, gbc);

    ln1tf = new JTextField("");
    ln1tf.setFont(plain);
    ln1tf.setEditable(true);
    ln1tf.addKeyListener(new AlphabeticList());
    gbc.insets = midMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.4;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(ln1tf, gbc);

    ln2tf = new JTextField("");
    ln2tf.setFont(plain);
    ln2tf.setEditable(true);
    ln2tf.addKeyListener(new AlphabeticList());
    gbc.insets = botMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.4;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(ln2tf, gbc);

    agetf = new JTextField("");
    agetf.setFont(plain);
    agetf.setEditable(true);
    agetf.addKeyListener(new NumericList());
    gbc.insets = topMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(agetf, gbc);

    pntf = new JTextField("");
    pntf.setFont(plain);
    pntf.setEditable(true);
    pntf.addKeyListener(new PhoneList());
    gbc.insets = midMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 0.1;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(pntf, gbc);

    addresstf = new JTextField("");
    addresstf.setFont(plain);
    addresstf.setEditable(true);
    addresstf.addKeyListener(new AddressList());
    gbc.insets = midMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(addresstf, gbc);

    emtf = new JTextField("");
    emtf.setFont(plain);
    emtf.setEditable(true);
    emtf.addKeyListener(new EmailList());
    gbc.insets = botMidTF;
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    dataIn.add(emtf, gbc);

    // My Traversal Policy
    compList.add(nametf);
    compList.add(ln1tf);
    compList.add(ln2tf);
    compList.add(agetf);
    compList.add(pntf);
    compList.add(addresstf);
    compList.add(emtf);
    dataIn.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MyFocusTraversalPolicy());

    // Table
    String[][] data = {};
    String[] headers = { "Id", "Name", "First Lastname", "Second Lastname", "Age", "Phone Number", "Address",
            "E-Mail" };

    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
    t = new JTable(dtm);
    t.setFont(plaint);
    header = t.getTableHeader();
    header.setFont(bold12);

    // Table Design
    int[] columnsWidth = { 65, 120, 120, 120, 40, 100, 300, 220 };
    int i = 0;
    for (int width : columnsWidth) {
        TableColumn column = t.getColumnModel().getColumn(i++);
        column.setMinWidth(width);
        column.setMaxWidth(width);
        column.setPreferredWidth(width);
    }

    // Columns Text Alignment
    DefaultTableCellRenderer rendererLeft = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    DefaultTableCellRenderer rendererCenter = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    TableColumnModel colModel = t.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn[] col = new TableColumn[t.getColumnCount()];

    for (int j = 0; j < t.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        col[j] = colModel.getColumn(j);
        switch (j) {
            case 0: {
                rendererCenter.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererCenter);
            }
                break;
            case 1: {
                rendererLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererLeft);
            }
                break;
            case 2: {
                rendererLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererLeft);
            }
                break;
            case 3: {
                rendererLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererLeft);
            }
                break;
            case 4: {
                rendererCenter.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererCenter);
            }
                break;
            case 5: {
                rendererCenter.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererCenter);
            }
                break;
            case 6: {
                rendererLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererLeft);
            }
                break;
            case 7: {
                rendererLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                col[j].setCellRenderer(rendererLeft);
            }
                break;
        }
    }

    // Insert table into ScrollPane
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(t);
    table.add(sp);
    t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1085, 230));

    // Buttons
    JPanel eastP = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));

    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    JButton del = new JButton("Delete");
    JButton edit = new JButton("Edit");
    JButton clr = new JButton("Clear");

    save.setFont(bold12);
    del.setFont(bold12);
    edit.setFont(bold12);
    clr.setFont(bold12);

    save.addActionListener(new Save());
    del.addActionListener(new Delete());
    edit.addActionListener(new Edit());
    clr.addActionListener(new Clear());
    t.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            rowSelected = t.getSelectedRow();
        }
    });

    eastP.add(save);
    eastP.add(del);
    eastP.add(edit);
    eastP.add(clr);
    buttons.add(eastP, BorderLayout.EAST);

    // Add to main
    mainP.add(dataIn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainP.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainP.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainF.setContentPane(mainP);
    mainF.pack();
    mainF.setVisible(true);
    mainF.setResizable(false);
    mainF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new UserFormNew();
        }
    });

}

//Focus Traversal Policy Custom Class
private class MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

    public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
        int currentPosition = compList.indexOf(aComponent);
        currentPosition = (currentPosition + 1) % compList.size();
        return (Component) compList.get(currentPosition);
    }

    public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
        int currentPosition = compList.indexOf(aComponent);
        currentPosition = (compList.size() + currentPosition - 1) % compList.size();
        return (Component) compList.get(currentPosition);
    }

    public Component getFirstComponent(Container cntnr) {
        return (Component) compList.get(0);
    }

    public Component getLastComponent(Container cntnr) {
        return (Component) compList.get(compList.size() - 1);
    }

    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container cntnr) {
        return (Component) compList.get(0);
    }

}

// Listener Classes
public class Save implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String name = nametf.getText();
        String ln1 = ln1tf.getText();
        String ln2 = ln2tf.getText();
        String age = agetf.getText();
        String pn = pntf.getText();
        String address = addresstf.getText();
        String em = emtf.getText();

        // Autogenerate id
        idCount++;

        // Data Into Table
        if (idCount == 0) {
            t.setValueAt(Integer.toString(idCount), 0, 0);
            t.setValueAt(name, 0, 1);
            t.setValueAt(ln1, 0, 2);
            t.setValueAt(ln2, 0, 3);
            t.setValueAt(age, 0, 4);
            t.setValueAt(pn, 0, 5);
            t.setValueAt(address, 0, 6);
            t.setValueAt(em, 0, 7);
        } else if (ed == true) {
            t.setValueAt(name, rowSelected, 1);
            t.setValueAt(ln1, rowSelected, 2);
            t.setValueAt(ln2, rowSelected, 3);
            t.setValueAt(age, rowSelected, 4);
            t.setValueAt(pn, rowSelected, 5);
            t.setValueAt(address, rowSelected, 6);
            t.setValueAt(em, rowSelected, 7);
            ed = false;
        } else {
            String[] newRow = { Integer.toString(idCount), name, ln1, ln2, age, pn, address, em };
            dtm.addRow(newRow);
        }

        idtf.setText("");
        nametf.setText("");
        ln1tf.setText("");
        ln2tf.setText("");
        agetf.setText("");
        pntf.setText("");
        addresstf.setText("");
        emtf.setText("");

    }

}

public class Delete implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dtm.removeRow(rowSelected);
    }

}

public class Edit implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ed = true;
        selRowInfoGotten = new String[t.getColumnCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < t.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            selRowInfoGotten[i] = (String) t.getValueAt(rowSelected, i);
        }

        idtf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[0]);
        nametf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[1]);
        ln1tf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[2]);
        ln2tf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[3]);
        agetf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[4]);
        pntf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[5]);
        addresstf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[6]);
        emtf.setText(selRowInfoGotten[7]);

    }

}

public class Clear implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (ed == false) {
            idtf.setText("");
            nametf.setText("");
            ln1tf.setText("");
            ln2tf.setText("");
            agetf.setText("");
            pntf.setText("");
            addresstf.setText("");
            emtf.setText("");
        } else {
            nametf.setText("");
            ln1tf.setText("");
            ln2tf.setText("");
            agetf.setText("");
            pntf.setText("");
            addresstf.setText("");
            emtf.setText("");
        }

    }

}

public class AlphabeticList implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Letters only
        char testChar = e.getKeyChar();
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(testChar)) {
            e.consume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {   
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            nametf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
            ln1tf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
            ln2tf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {    }

}

public class NumericList implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Numbers only
        char testChar = e.getKeyChar();
        if (!Character.isDigit(testChar)) {
            e.consume();
        }
        // 3-digit ages max
        String ageText = agetf.getText();
        int ageLength = ageText.length();
        if (ageLength >= 3) {
            e.consume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            agetf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}

public class AddressList implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            addresstf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}

public class PhoneList implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Numbers only
        char testChar = e.getKeyChar();
        if (!Character.isDigit(testChar)) {
            e.consume();
        }
        String pnText = pntf.getText();
        int pnLength = pnText.length();
        // Add hyphens
        if (pnLength == 3 || pnLength == 7) {
            pntf.setText(pnText + "-");
        }
        // 10-digit numbers
        if (pnLength >= 12) {
            e.consume();
        }
        // Erase even hyphens
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
            String pnTxt = pntf.getText();
            int start = 0;
            int end = pnLength - 2;
            String pnErased = pnTxt.substring(start, end);
            System.out.println(
                    "PNLength: " + pnLength + ", Start: " + start + ", End: " + end + ", PNErased: " + pnErased);
            pntf.setText(pnErased);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            pntf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}

public class EmailList implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            emtf.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I have a much smaller example user form where I added a focus traversal policy.

The code has two parts.  While I'm constructing the GUI, I set my focus traversal policy.  I put all of the JTextFields into a List in the order that I want them traversed.  Every editable field in the JPanel must be included in this List.

I also wrote a class that extends FocusTraversalPolicy.  I made it private and included it in the view class.  That seems like an appropriate place to put the class.  You can put it in a separate file if you want.

Here's the code.  You can compile it, run it, and see that tabbing through the form follows the columns.  This is what we like to call a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class UserForm {

    // top, left, bottom, right
    private static final Insets topInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    private static final Insets topCenterInsets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10);
    private static final Insets middleInsets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10);
    private static final Insets middleCenterInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 10);

    public UserForm() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("User Form");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Miscelaneous
        Font plain = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        Font bold11 = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11);
        Font bold12 = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        // Data-In Form Components
        JLabel idl = new JLabel("Id:");
        idl.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, idl, 0, gridy, 1, 1, topInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField idtf = new JTextField(40);
        idtf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, idtf, 1, gridy, 1, 1, topCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel agl = new JLabel("Age:");
        agl.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, agl, 2, gridy, 1, 1, topCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField agtf = new JTextField(40);
        agtf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, agtf, 3, gridy++, 1, 1, topCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel namel = new JLabel("Name:");
        namel.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, namel, 0, gridy, 1, 1, middleInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField nametf = new JTextField(40);
        nametf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, nametf, 1, gridy, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel adl = new JLabel("Address:");
        adl.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, adl, 2, gridy, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField adtf = new JTextField(40);
        adtf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, adtf, 3, gridy++, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel pnl = new JLabel("Phone Number:");
        pnl.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, pnl, 0, gridy, 1, 1, middleInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField pntf = new JTextField(40);
        pntf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, pntf, 1, gridy, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel ln1l = new JLabel("First Lastname:");
        ln1l.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, ln1l, 2, gridy, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField ln1tf = new JTextField(40);
        ln1tf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, ln1tf, 3, gridy++, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel ln2l = new JLabel("Second Lastname:");
        ln2l.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, ln2l, 0, gridy, 1, 1, middleInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField ln2tf = new JTextField(40);
        ln2tf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, ln2tf, 1, gridy, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel eml = new JLabel("E-Mail:");
        eml.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(mainPanel, eml, 2, gridy, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE);

        JTextField emtf = new JTextField(40);
        emtf.setFont(plain);
        addComponent(mainPanel, emtf, 3, gridy++, 1, 1, middleCenterInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        List<Component> order = new ArrayList<>(8);
        order.add(idtf);
        order.add(nametf);
        order.add(pntf);
        order.add(ln2tf);
        order.add(agtf);
        order.add(adtf);
        order.add(ln1tf);
        order.add(emtf);
        MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy newPolicy = new MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(newPolicy);

        // JTable Creation
        String[] headline = { "Id", "Name", "First Lastname", "Second Lastname", "Age", "Address", "Phone Number",
                "E-Mail" };
        String[][] data = { { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" }, { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } };
        JTable dataShow = new JTable(data, headline);
        dataShow.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(900, 300));
        dataShow.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dataShow);
        addComponent(mainPanel, scrollPane, 0, gridy++, 4, 1, middleInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // Table Personalization
        dataShow.getTableHeader().setFont(bold11);
        new HeaderRenderer(dataShow);

        // buttons Components
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(buttonPanel, save, 0, 0, 1, 1, topInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JButton del = new JButton("Delete");
        del.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(buttonPanel, del, 1, 0, 1, 1, topInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JButton edit = new JButton("Edit");
        edit.setFont(bold12);
        addComponent(buttonPanel, edit, 2, 0, 1, 1, topInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        addComponent(mainPanel, buttonPanel, 0, gridy++, 4, 1, middleInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // set content pane
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // For future table filling
        /*
         * String ids = idtf.getText(); String names = nametf.getText(); String ln1s =
         * ln1tf.getText(); String ln2s = ln2tf.getText(); String ags = agtf.getText();
         * String ads = adtf.getText(); String pns = pntf.getText(); String ems =
         * emtf.getText();
         */

    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth,
            int gridheight, Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0, anchor, fill,
                insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // invoke runnable for thread safety
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new UserForm();
            }
        });

    }

    // LEFT alignment renderer
    private class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;

        public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
            renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
            renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int col) {
            return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        }

    }

    private class MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

        private List<Component> componentList;

        public MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(List<Component> componentList) {
            this.componentList = componentList;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer, Component aComponent) {
            int index = getComponentIndex(aComponent);
            index++;
            index = (index >= componentList.size()) ? 0 : index;
            return componentList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container aContainer, Component aComponent) {
            int index = getComponentIndex(aComponent);
            index--;
            index = (index < 0) ? index + componentList.size() : index;
            return componentList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return componentList.get(0);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return componentList.get(componentList.size() - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return componentList.get(0);
        }

        private int getComponentIndex(Component test) {
            for (int i = 0; i < componentList.size(); i++) {
                Component component = componentList.get(i);
                if (component.equals(test)) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gilbert, thanks again.
I ran your example code, i only edited the order List values, since idtf is uneditable and hence desirably "untabbable".
The list remained as follows:
List<Component> order = new ArrayList<>(7);
        order.add(nametf);
        order.add(ln1tf);
        order.add(ln2tf);
        order.add(agtf);
        order.add(pntf);
        order.add(adtf);
        order.add(emtf);
        
When ran, tab leaps from nametf to pntf, to ln1tf, to adtf, to ln2tf, to emtf, never touching agtf. Sadly ain't working for me still =(